# Querying objects in a View in DJANGO

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a django model called destination.  I have another model called tours.  Tours consist of destinations and other elements.  In  my VIEW for destinations, I want to have available a Tour List containing all the Tours associated with a particular destination.  I'm not sure how to write it out.  this is what I have:

```
from django.template import Context, loader
from ceibelize.destinations.models import Destination
from ceibelize.tours.models import Tour
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def detail(request, destination_id):
    dest_object = get_object_or_404(Destination, pk=destination_id) *****
    tours_in = get_object_or_404(Tour, Tour.destination=destination_id)
    t = loader.get_template('destinations/detail.html')
    c = Context({
        'dest_object':dest_object,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

*** Is where I'm trying to figure out how to query the Tour object.  Tours and destinations have a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_object_or_404()` will get you only a single object. Filter instead.

```
tours_in = Tour.objects.filter(destination=destination_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Smarty pants! :D